# Renaming the content in a text file?

Tags: bash, for-loop, rename, deep-copy, renaming

So I have a text file (named f1.txt) that contains the following:

```
subj00000_xyz
subj00001_xyz
subj00002_xyz
subj00003_xyz
subj00004_xyz
```

Now I have another text file (named f2.txt) contains the following:

```
subj0001_01_pat
subj0001_03_pat
subj0002_03_pat
subj0004_01_pat
subj0005_01_pat
```

after renaming I want each line to be:

```
subj0001_01_xyz
subj0001_03_xyz
subj0002_03_xyz
subj0004_01_xyz
subj0005_01_xyz
```

So .. I want the first part "subj0001_01" to be from f2.txt, and keep the rest of the naming convention from f2.txt "_xyz"..

So, the thing is each subject (or line) in `f1.txt` corresponds to the same line in `f2.txt`.
For example: `subj00003` corresponds to `subj0004_01`.
My question is this:

How can I rename the content (each line) in `f1.txt` so that it has the names from `f2.txt` instead?

Also, the content in each file is very different..it is a directory to a specific file, so I don't want to override it.  I want to rename each.

I was thinking of doing something like this:
`i=0
for s in f2.txt; do ss=$(printf '%05d' $i); echo ${ss}.nii $s; ((i++)); done`

To recap, I want contents of f1.txt to be edited or renamed. by replacing "subj00001" in f1.txt to be replaced the "subj0001_01" from f2.txt.

Comment: `cp -f [original file] [new file]`  If all you want to do is replace `f1.txt` with `f2.txt`, just replace the file.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck at? / Try using some scripting languages.

Comment: It does look like all you want is replace `f1.txt` with `f2.txt`. If it isn't, you should indicate *how* it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn’t want to rename the files you could maybe try `sed`

```
sed -i 's/pat/xyz/g' f2.txt
```

The `s` means substitute “pat” for “xyz” and the `g` means globally. By default `sed` will stop on first match. Lastly the `-i` means inplace

Comment: But I want f1.txt to be editted or renamed. 
by replacing "subj00001" f1.txt to be replaced the "subj0001_01" from f2.txt.